# How can I get the name of the column clicked using jQuery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using the jQuery tablesorter plugin to sort a gridview in an asp.net application.  I can capture the column index but can't seem to figure out how to get the column name.

This is what I'm doing:

```
var currentSort;

        $('#gvTickets').tablesorter({
            // sort on the last column, order asc 
            sortList: [[9, 0]]
        }).bind("sortEnd", function(sorter) {
            currentSort = sorter.target.config.sortList;

        });
```

Here is the html:

```
<div>
<table class="stretchalltable" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="gvTickets" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="header" style="cursor: pointer; ">Requester</th><th scope="col" class="header" style="cursor: pointer; ">Subject</th><th scope="col" class="header" style="cursor: pointer; ">Type</th><th scope="col" class="header" style="cursor: pointer; ">Category</th><th scope="col" class="header" style="cursor: pointer; ">Priority</th><th scope="col" class="header" style="cursor: pointer; ">Status</th><th scope="col" class="header" style="cursor: pointer; ">Due</th><th scope="col" class="header" style="cursor: pointer; ">Assigned To</th><th scope="col" class="header" style="cursor: pointer; ">Created</th><th scope="col" class="header headerSortUp" style="cursor: pointer; ">Days</th>
        </tr>
    </thead><tbody>

    <tr>
            <td>JMAULDIN</td><td><a href="ticket2.aspx?action=edit&amp;ticket_id=7827">Van Order Entry Customer Contract Lookup Display</a></td><td>Project</td><td>Portal </td><td>Normal</td><td>On Hold</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Nathan Baker - Doozer</td><td>27-DEC-2011</td><td>133</td>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:#E6E6E6;">
            <td>RCRITTENDEN</td><td><a href="ticket2.aspx?action=edit&amp;ticket_id=8190">Cap changes</a></td><td>Project</td><td>Portal </td><td>Normal</td><td>On Hold</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Nathan Baker - Doozer</td><td>02-FEB-2012</td><td>106</td>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:#E6E6E6;">
            <td>JMAULDIN</td><td><a href="ticket2.aspx?action=edit&amp;ticket_id=8796">Online SRN  -- Add email SRN like print SRN</a></td><td>Project</td><td>Portal </td><td>Normal</td><td>New</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Nathan Baker - Doozer</td><td>15-MAR-2012</td><td>76</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>JMAULDIN</td><td><a href="ticket2.aspx?action=edit&amp;ticket_id=9058">SES AST field not saving correctly.</a></td><td>Project</td><td>Portal </td><td>Normal</td><td>On Hold</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Nathan Baker - Doozer</td><td>20-MAR-2012</td><td>73</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>RAVRIETT</td><td><a href="ticket2.aspx?action=edit&amp;ticket_id=9470">Copy Project Plan (ignore deleted items)</a></td><td>Support Task</td><td>Loaned Item </td><td>Normal</td><td>New</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Nathan Baker - Doozer</td><td>24-APR-2012</td><td>48</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>TCACCAM</td><td><a href="ticket2.aspx?action=edit&amp;ticket_id=9670">WEB: Contracts Administration</a></td><td>Support Task</td><td>Portal </td><td>High</td><td>New</td><td>14-MAY-2012</td><td>Nathan Baker - Doozer</td><td>14-MAY-2012</td><td>34</td>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:#E6E6E6;">
            <td>DOOZER1</td><td><a href="ticket2.aspx?action=edit&amp;ticket_id=10041">nb test</a></td><td>Project</td><td>Portal </td><td>Normal</td><td>New</td><td>13-JUN-2012</td><td>Nathan Baker - Doozer</td><td>13-JUN-2012</td><td>12</td>
        </tr></tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

### Update

Thank you to fudgey for your replies.  I can't seem to get this to work no matter what I try.  Basically what I need to do is in the jquery tablesorter, I need to have the sortList value be a variable.  It would need to look like this:

```
var currentSort;

    $('#gvTickets').tablesorter({
        // sort on the last column, order asc 
        sortList: currentSort
    }).bind("sortEnd", function(sorter) {
        currentSort = sorter.target.config.sortList;

    });
```

I need to store the currentSort in Session and retrieve it via an ajax call then sort the grid in the same way it was last viewed.  If the user hits the page, sorts the grid, leaves the page and then returns I need it to be sorted in the same way as the last time they were on the page as long as it's within the scope of the session state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the index to find the text from the header - it might even be easier to use the saved `headerList` like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/24/)):

```
$('#gvTickets')
    .tablesorter({
        // sort on the last column, order asc 
        sortList: [[9, 0]]
    })
    .bind("sortEnd", function(event) {
        var table = event.target,
            currentSort = table.config.sortList,
            // target the first sorted column
            columnNum = currentSort[0][0],
            columnName = $(table.config.headerList[columnNum]).text();

        console.log(columnName);

    });​
```

Comment: Hi fudgey, thank you very much for your answer.  I have another question for you or anyone else that might know.  Is it possible to set the sortList to a variable like this sortList: currentSort?  It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sadly, the original version of tablesorter (2.0.5) doesn't save the current sortList. But I do have a fork of [tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) on github which updates the `table.config.sortList` with the current sort, if you are interested.

Comment: Hi fudgey, what I am trying to do is save the sort order in session so if the user leaves the page and returns the grid is sorted the way they had it.  Will your version work for this?  I can successfully save and retrieve the sort order to/from session but when I try to set sortList: [[currentSort]] it's not working.

Comment: I made a widget named `saveSort` for it... here is a [demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html). The widget should work with the original version of tablesorter, but I haven't tested it lately.

Comment: Hi fudgey, I downloaded the following jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js and added it to the page with the table.  I also changed the jquery to this but it doesn't seem to work.  Am I missing something?  $('#gvTickets').tablesorter({
                widgets: ["saveSort", "zebra"]
            });

Comment: You're right, I just tested the saveSort widget and it won't work with the original tablesorter... sorry =(

Answer (score 2):

You can also capture it outside, anywhere else (e.g. in your function, start of ajax, ..), and only when needed and not on every click, with a bit less overhead  like this:

```
lastSortList=$("#mytable")[0].config.sortList;
```

And example for sorting it back after ajax update:

```
$("#mytable").trigger("sorton", [lastSortList]);
```

Remember to declare the first line in the right scope though.